# Unable to restart or delete jenkins cartridge in OpenShift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have an OpenShift application with a jenkins cartridge installed.  Something happened when I was deploying the build.  Now I am not able to restart or delete the jenkins cartridge.

When I try to restart the cartridge I get the following error:

`Unexpected error: User does not exist in cgroups: 53288f5de0b8cd7aad0002ee`

When I try to delete the cartridge I just get "We appear to be having technical difficulties"

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email openshift@redhat.com with your openshift username, application url, and give us permission to look at your gear, and reference this stack overflow question.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I just sent the email off.

Comment: Thanks for deleting the Jenkins cartridge! And thanks for the fast response Openshift!